# Uniform continuity of Convolution with given conditions.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove or Disprove: Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ is locally integrable, and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous with compact support. Prove or disprove. If $f$ is bounded, then $f * g$ is uniformly continuous.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$ (TRUE). Reasoning, $|f(x-y) - f(t-y)| \to 0$ since $f$ is bounded. $$ \bigg| \int_{K} f(x-y)g(y) dy - \int_K f(t-y)g(y) \, dy\bigg| - \bigg| \int_K g(y) ( f(x-y) - f(t-y) ) dy \bigg| $$
$$\le \int_K |g(y)| | f(x-y) - f(t-y)| \,dy \le \int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(y)| | f(x-y) - f(t-y)| \, dy $$
Since $f$ is bounded, $\forall x, t  \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $ | f(x-y) - f(t -y )|=0$ as $y \to \infty$. Thus, $\forall \epsilon$ we have $ \frac{\epsilon}{2 m(K) M}$ such that $ | f(x-y) - f(t-y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2 m(K) M}$. Let $y_n \to \infty$, as $n \to \infty$, then whenever $| x - t| < \delta$, there exists $N$ such that $$ |f(x-y_n) - f(t-y_n)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2 m(K) M}$$ for all $n \ge N$.   Then $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(y)| |f(x-y) - f(t-y)| \, dy \le  \frac{\epsilon}{2 m(K) M} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(y)| \,dy$$
$$ \le \frac{\epsilon}{2 m(K) M} \int_K |g(y)| \,dy$$ Since $g(y)$ compactly supported and continuous, we must have that $g(y)$ bounded, and thus $|g(y)| <M$, and thus, $$  \frac{\epsilon}{2 m(K) M} \int_K |g(y)| \,dy < \epsilon$$

I am feeling a bit uneasy about my proof. Is it valid?

Comment: What do you mean by $|f(x-y) - f(t-y)| \to 0$?  As $x\to\infty$?  As $y\to-\infty$?  As $t\to\text{something}$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: QUOTE Since $f$ is bounded, $\forall x, t  \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $ | f(x-y) - f(t -y )|=0$ as $y \to \infty$. END QUOTE  That doesn't make sense.  That is true if $f$ has bounded support, but "$f$ is bounded" normally means the set of _values_ $f$ can assume is bounded, not that the support is bounded. ${}\qquad{}$